# Productivity of Corson's property (C)

Tags: banach-spaces

H.H. Corson in [C] introduced the following version of Lindelöf property for convex closed subsets of Banach spaces:

> A Banach space $X$ has *property (C)* if every family of convex closed subsets of $X$ with empty intersection contains a countable subfamily with empty intersection.

For instance, all weakly Lindelöf Banach spaces have property (C), but there is an example of a space with property (C) which is not weakly Lindelöf (see [C]).

There are several characterisations of spaces with property (C), eg. in terms of duals (cf. [P]):

> A space $X$ has property (C) if and only if for every $A\subseteq B_{X^*}$ and $f\in\overline{A}^{w^*}$ there exists countable $A'\subseteq A$ such that $f\in\overline{\text{conv}}^{w^*}A'$.

The property (C) passes to closed subspaces and quotients. Thus, a natural question concerning products arises:

> Assume $X$ has property (C). Does $X\times X$ have it as well?

I haven't been able to find any answers or hints concerning this question. However it seems to be basic... I am especially interested in the case of spaces $C(K)$ of continuous real-valued functions on a compact space $K$ with the supremum norm:

> Assume $C(K)$ has property (C). Do $C(K)\times C(K)$ and $C(K\times K)$ have also property (C)?

Thank you very much for any answer or comment.

**References**

[C] H.H. Corson, The weak topology of a Banach space, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 101 (1961), 1–15.

[P] R. Pol, On a question of H.H. Corson and some related problems, Fund. Math. 109 (1980), 143–154.

Comment: The analogy with Lindelöfness might suggest it to be false, as Lindelöf is not productive at all (e.g. the Sorgenfrey line). But maybe the structure of convex sets helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, if $X$ and $Y$ have property (C), then so does $X\oplus Y$ because property (C) is a three-space property; this is a result of Pol (Proposition 1 in the paper you are referring to).

However, I am not sure if it is known whether property (C) passes from $C(K)$ to $C(K\times K)$. (If this is true, it should follow rather easily from the identification $C(K\times K) = C(K)\otimes_{\varepsilon}C(K)$ and the structure of convex sets in the injective tensor products---otherwise perhaps there is a counter-example.)

Comment: Thanks, Tomek. I have known the result of Pol you refer to, but completely didn't link it with my question.